# Is it wrong to expect resumable functions actually resume in the original thread?

Tags: c++

After watching the [interview](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-39-await-co-routines) with Gor Nishanov on await and coroutines, I decided to toy a bit with resumable functions [N4131](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4134.pdf). I then realized that the following code printed 'false' to my second question (tested with Visual Studio 2015 RC and the [online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) (requires flag: `/await`)):

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

struct Foo
{
  future<void> coro(thread::id ui_thread_id)
  {
    cout << "Q: awaiting result in UI thread? " << boolalpha << (this_thread::get_id() == ui_thread_id) << endl;
    auto intermediate_result = __await async([] {
      this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
      return 42;
    });
    cout << "Q: received result in UI thread? " << boolalpha << (this_thread::get_id() == ui_thread_id) << endl;
    result = intermediate_result; // race
  }

  int result = 0;
};

int main()
{
  const auto ui_thread_id = this_thread::get_id();
  Foo f;
  auto c = f.coro(ui_thread_id);
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
  {
    cout << "  -- event loop: " << f.result << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
  }
  c.wait();
}
```

My expectation resulted from the statement that "the fact that a function is implemented as resumable function is unobservable by the caller" ([N4131](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4134.pdf), p.8, Resumable Function, 4th paragraph).

This seems to be an important detail and I could not find any statement in [N4131](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4134.pdf) which clarifies my question.

Is it wrong to expect resumable functions actually resume their work in the original thread? If it is wrong, please try to explain why?

Comment: I was under the impression that `std::async()` is the resumable function in this case and thus `Foo::coro()` would be the caller.

Comment: The statement you are referring to means that from function declaration say `future<int> read()` as a caller you won't be able to know if it is implemented as resumable or with usual threads: `read().get()` will block until result is available and simple `read()` will not. As for your initial question, in c# they try to make `await` predictable and resume in UI thread but only if it was started inside message loop. Most likely in c++ standard this will be undefined behavior and say in microsoft implementation they would add more strict guaranties. But it's just a guess based on common sense.

Comment: @frymode, "unobservable" should probably be interpreted as you suggest it. It is definitely concerning that this seemingly innocent piece of code results in undefined behavior (C++11 1.3.10) because of the data race on the `result` assignment.

Comment: For the record, that code doesn't compile in the online compiler. What flags are you passing it?

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois, it requires `/await`. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Practical example where your expectation is wrong: when you are working with threadpools (i.e. most of the times when *not* doing ui stuff) this would harm performance because code would fight over running on the same thread when there are other threads being idle. Also sometimes it's not even possible to resume on the same thread because threads can come and go in a threadpool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, it is probably wrong to expect resumable functions actually resume their work in the original thread because the proposal is underspecified with regards to that behavior (maybe on purpose, maybe not).

I think your misconception is around *which* function is resumable in the example, and thus which function is bound by "the fact that a function is implemented as resumable function is unobservable by the caller".

From the proposal (emphasis mine):

> A function or a lambda is called resumable function or resumable lambda if a **body of the function or
>   lambda contains at least one suspend/resume point**. Suspend/resume points are expressions with one
>   or more await operators, yield statements or await-for statements

This means that the lambda isn't the resumable function, `coro` is because the `await` keyword is part of its body. The proposal specifies how the resumable function behaves with regards to its callers and the example shows that it is indeed unobservable by the caller, `main()` in this case, whether it was implemented as resumable or not (`main()` is also still on the UI thread when `coro` returns).

Now, one could argue that this might be an oversight in the proposal to not specify this but I'm sure there was a good reason for it, yet I wasn't able to find anything in the proposal relating to the actual resuming of the function.

There could also be debate around the interaction with modifiable parameters. For example:

```
future<void> coro(thread::id ui_thread_id, int* foo)
{
  auto intermediate_result = __await async([] {
    this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
  });

  *foo = 42;
}
```

I would personally consider the fact that `foo` can be modified by another thread as "observable" from the caller, but then again someone could likely argue otherwise (I'm not the greatest at standard-ese).

Last but not least, I'm not sure what you consider extraordinarily race-y about the assignment to result. It does race with the reads in `main()` but you wrote the code specifically for this and there's only one assignment (the body of the function is suspended at the `await` call and resumed once the async lambda returns). Changing `await` to resume on the same thread would not affect this situation at all (except in the case of non-atomic read-writes where you could read an object in an inconsistent state, which is another can of worms and is probably a valid point).

Note that this feature is very young and currently only experimentally implemented in MSVC IIRC so I would expect it to go through some changes before it's standardized (if it ever is). There's also a non-negligible chance that this is actually specification/implementation bug.

That being said, there's a good chance that the behavior on resuming resumable functions was barely specified to allow more freedom in the implementation.

Comment: Great answer. You are right about my misunderstanding of which one was actually the resumable function. I thought about the race issue again and I think the resumable function `coro()` should have returned a `future<int>` and not `future<void>`.

Comment: @HaukeHeibel In any case, I was convinced the answer was a clear no when I started but I'm not so sure it's that clear-cut now. It's really underspecified. Also thanks for bringing up that proposal, it was the first time I heard of it :)